# Spacing issues between Chrome and Firefox/IE

Tags: html, css

I'm getting weird spacing issues between Chrome and FF. Chrome (pic 2) looks fine but in FF (pic 1) there's larger spacing. I'm quite sure it's tied to `text-align:justify;`.

*EDIT* On closer inspection it looks like `word-break:break-all;` is not being rendered in FF and IE!

```
.project_miniwrap { position:absolute;   
width:59%;
margin: auto;
top: 23%; left: 0; right: 0; text-align:justify; } 

.project-link {
font-family: 'Arial-BoldMT';
color:#262626;
font-size:50px;
word-break:break-all;
line-height:63px;
text-decoration:none;       
border-bottom: solid transparent 2px;
letter-spacing: -2px; }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers render text spacing differently even if you have the `letter-spacing` property.

Best bet is to try to use browser specific CSS and adjust each one accordingly until you get the spacing you need.

Comment: On closer look it's actually `word-break:break-all;` not being rendered in FF and IE.

Comment: Interesting. From what I kept reading it was just a different browser issue. Now I learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

I simply had to add `word-break:break-all;` to the wrapping container for it to work in FF and IE. Dunno why.